# Does doing tasks 'more fully' grant additional XP?

Tags: mass-effect-3

For example, clearing out the Reaper infection within the geth consensus grants +75 XP in the first round. If I diligently clear up every little glowing yellow block, will I be granted more XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the quest. In the Geth VR thing you will not be granted additional XP for destroying more blocks than necessary, but you will be granted extra XP for locating extra clues during investigation phases of the Leviathan DLC.

Answer (score 2):

No, clearing the entire yellow cube is not necessary, just enough to get to where you need to go (i.e. unblock the path).  The reward is the same either way.